# Stars and Bars with small constraint.

Tags: probability

So this seems to be a basic Stars and Bars question but I cannot find a way to truly solve it.
$a+b+2c=8$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive integers. Using Stars and Bars you get more answers, and I attempted complementary counting but I'm not sure exactly what to subtract from what I got. Basic stars and bars if $a+b+c=8$ gives you $21$, but that includes the times when $2c$ is odd, which doesn't work. How can you find how many times $2c$ is odd, or is there an easy way to solve these questions?

Comment: Did you mean to say that $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ are **positive** integers? Or at least **non-negative** integers?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake

Comment: Let $a = a' + 1, b = b' + 1, c = c' + 1$ to have $a',b',c'$ all be non-negative integers.

Comment: Typically you will get several downvotes if you don't post what you have attempted first. Your question is fine, but you mention that you attempted a solution but you weren't sure what to do with it. That's completely fine, but post what you attempted. Even if completely wrong we are all here to help anyway, and can explain most confusion.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are a restricted number of possibilities for $c$, so find the values for each $a+b=n-2c$ and add them up

Comment: As indicated by the comment of @Henry, $(c)$ must be an element in $\{1,2,3\}$.  Let $f(c)$ denote the number of satisfying solutions for each value of $(c)$.  Then, you want the $$\sum_{c=1}^3 f(c),$$ where $f(c)$ is the number of positive integer solutions to $$a + b = (8 - 2c).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $a + b = 8 - 2c$ is even.  That means either $a$ and $b$ are both even or they are both odd.

If $a$ and $b$ are both even, then $a = 2a'$ and $b = 2b'$, where $a'$ and $b'$ are positive integers.  Then
\begin{align*}
a + b + 2c & = 8\\
2a' + 2b' + 2c & = 8\\
a' + b' + c' & = 4
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the positive integers.

If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then $a = 2a' - 1$ and $b = 2b' - 1$, where $a'$ and $b'$ are both positive integers.  Then
\begin{align*}
a + b + 2c & = 8\\
2a' - 1 + 2b' - 1 + 2c & = 8\\
2a' + 2b' + 2c & = 10\\
a' + b' + c & = 5
\end{align*}
which is an equation in the positive integers.

Can you finish the problem?